# Can i play an audio() on a browser in my smartphone?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a game of arkanoid with the p5js library and I want to put some sound effect along with it. When I play the game on a browser in my computer it works correctly, but when i play in my smartphone the sounf¿d doesnt play and it gives me this error, I was wondering if someone could help me, please!!

```
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = -2;

    this.sonido = new Audio("http://k007.kiwi6.com/hotlink/zf8e3af0c2/Bounce.wav");
```

}

When it bounces in a wall or the player it should make the sound, in a computer works but not in the smartphone.
The error is the following: uncaught (in promise) notallowederror play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, on mobile the user has to click on something to allow JavaScript to play sounds. This is a [security measure](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

To be able to play sounds on mobile:

- The user has to interact with the website (buttons, etc.)

This issue is known at p5js. You can find a workflow to fix your issue on their bug-tracker: https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/249

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to let you know that I solved the problem, I just had to change the format of the audio from .wav to .mp3. Now it works perfectly :)